# Where should I code in Fragment that it will run only once- android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-tablelayout

I am implementing Tab Layout with Swipeable Views in android. For implementation I had followed

[AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

and

[Tabs and swipe views](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tabs-and-swipe-views/?lang=en).

But with both, I am facing the same problem. I am having 3 fragments but when my application run, `onCreateView` of 1st and 2nd `Fragment` called instead of only of 1st fragment's. When I swipe and go to 2nd fragment, onCreateView of 3rd Fragments get called.
So, whatever I code in 2nd fragment execute in the first fragment view. I researched and came to know that it happen to keep the next fragment into memory for smooth animation. But I am wondering, where I would code in the fragment so that it will execute only once or how to restrict  `Fragment getItem()` method to be called only once. What can be the solution for this?

Comment: If you have some specific code you want to only be executed once, you could place it in the container of your ViewPager. Fragments are destroyed when they are moved out of range to save memory

Comment: How can I code in a container of ViewPager. Can you provide any example.?

Comment: the ViewPager is inside an activity (or fragment), right? You have to code on the `onCreate` of that activity (or fragment).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Fragment's documentation you can implement the `onCreate()` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.

This should fix your problem, because i guess you now only use the `onCreateView` which might be called more than once.

For more information you can check the [Fragment's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) or [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)